# pjsip video on android does not full screen

Tags: android, video, pjsip

When I make video call, the video does not match the SurfaceView, the video is stretched. What should I do to make it full the SurfaceView? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: without any code we cant just help you.

Comment: @GastónSaillén I build the demo according to pjsip official guide, and I did not modify any code, do you know why?

Comment: first i dont know who is pjsip official guide, and if you dont post any code on what you are doing and what have you tried we cant help you, there is too much answers for this post, also in your question you never mentioned that you are usign a guide to do your job...

Comment: `VidCodecParam para = ((Endpoint)(ep)).getVideoCodecParam("H264");
            MediaFormatVideo encFmt = para.getEncFmt();
            encFmt.setWidth(240);
            encFmt.setHeight(320);
            ep.setVideoCodecParam("H264", para);`

Comment: Thanks,I use these code to control video size, but I dont know the suitable width and height, how to get the width and height please?

Comment: width and height of the device screen  ?

Answer (score 0):

To get width and height of the device you should use this

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

and then just put that data inside your MediaFormatVideo like this

```
    VidCodecParam para = ((Endpoint)(ep)).getVideoCodecParam("H264"); 
MediaFormatVideo encFmt = para.getEncFmt(); encFmt.setWidth(width); 
encFmt.setHeight(height); ep.setVideoCodecParam("H264", para);
```

you can also get width and height with this two methods

```
public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}

public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}
```

and then just do the same

```
    VidCodecParam para = ((Endpoint)(ep)).getVideoCodecParam("H264"); 
MediaFormatVideo encFmt = para.getEncFmt(); encFmt.setWidth(getScreenWidth()); 
encFmt.setHeight(getScreenHeight()); ep.setVideoCodecParam("H264", para);
```

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with screen resolution. That's a voip call, and I'm new on voip. This problem confused me for a long time